# AttributeError at /accounts/login/ 'dict' object has no attribute 'status_code'

Tags: python, html, django

I got an error, `AttributeError at /accounts/login/
'dict' object has no attribute 'status_code'`.  My web site's page has q login & new account registration in a page. I wrote in views.py

```
def login(request):
    login_form = LoginForm(request.POST)
    regist_form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
    if regist_form.is_valid():
        user = regist_form.save(commit=False)
        context = {
            'user': request.user,
            'login_form': login_form,
            'regist_form': regist_form,
        }

        return context

    if login_form.is_valid():
        user = login_form.save(commit=False)
        login(request, user)
        context = {
            'user': request.user,
            'login_form': login_form,
            'regist_form': regist_form,
        }
        return context

    context = {
        'login_form': login_form,
        'regist_form': regist_form,
    }
    return render(request, 'registration/accounts/login.html', context)
```

in login.html (I cannot user code format,so I decide to use code snippet)

```html
<header class="clearfix">
          <h1 class="title">WEB SITE</h1>
    
          <ul>
            <form class="form-inline" method="post" role="form">
              {% csrf_token %}
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="white-letter">LOGIN</label>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only">USERNAME</label>
                <input id="id_username" name="username" type="text" value="" minlength="5" maxlength="12" placeholder="USERNAME" class="form-control">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only">PASSWORD</label>
                <input id="id_password" name="password" type="password" value="" minlength="8" maxlength="12" placeholder="PASSWORD" class="form-control">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" style="color:white;background-color: #F62459;border-style: none;">LOGIN</button>
                <input name="next" type="hidden"/>
              </div>
            </form>
          </ul>
  </header>

  <main>
   <div class="heading col-lg-6 col-md-12"> 
    <h2>NEW ACCOUNT</h2>
    <h3 class="margin-small">ALL FREE</h3> 

    <form class="form-horizontal" method="POST"> 
      <div class="form-group-lg"> 
        <label for="id_username">USERNAME</label>
             {{ regist_form.username }} 
      </div>  
      <div class="form-group-lg"> 
        <label for="id_email">EMAIL</label>
              {{ regist_form.email }}
      </div>  
      <div class="form-group-lg"> 
        <label for="id_password">PASSWORD</label> 
         {{ regist_form.password1 }} 
      </div>  
      <div class="form-group-lg">
        <label for="id_password">PASSWORD（CONFORMATION）</label> 
         {{ regist_form.password2 }}
         <p class="help-block">{{ regist_form.password2.help_text }}</p> 
      </div>  
      <div class="form-group-lg">
        <div class="col-xs-offset-2">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" style="color:white;background-color: #F62459;border-style: none;">SUBMIT</button> 
        <input name="next" type="hidden"/> 
        </div>
      </div>
      {% csrf_token %} 
    </form> 
    </div>
    </div>
  </main>
```

Traceback says

```
Traceback:

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
  39.             response = get_response(request)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/deprecation.py" in __call__
  138.             response = self.process_response(request, response)

File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/middleware/common.py" in process_response
  115.         if response.status_code == 404:

Exception Type: AttributeError at /accounts/login/
Exception Value: 'dict' object has no attribute 'status_code'
```

I really cannot understand why this error happens.
How should I fix this?

Comment: As Selcuk says returning the context is your issue. See [Working with forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/#the-view) for a snippet to follow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Django views must return `HttpResponse` instances. You are returning a `dict` here:

```
return context
```